# What is a firmware tool, and is it possible to get one for personal use?

Tags: hard-drive

I recently had some issues with my WD Blue (mobile) HDD. A search led me to this guide: http://www.hddoracle.com/viewtopic.php?f=86&t=848 describing how to fix the issue. However, it requires a firmware tool, and my search for what that is and how I could get one has only given me more confusion. Thus, I was hoping someone else could explain how I might obtain a firmware tool. Sorry if I sound completely naive.

Comment: A firmware tool allows accessing the drive's firmware directly for editing in a hex editor.  The firmware is stored on the drive's PCB_(for mechanical HDD's, the external PCB on the bottom of the drive, and for SSDs, it's built into the SSD's PCB)_.  In the link, the screenshot is of a hex editor, showing what hex location needs to be edited in the firmware's module 0002 and what hex values to change to _(hex values are specified in a two-character hexadecimal pair format of `0 - 9` `A - F`; examples from the link's screenshot `4F`, `44`, `1E`, etc.)_

Comment: I would not edit the firmware on that drive, unless you need a new door stop.